# Manual fft not giving me same results as fft

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, fft

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

curve = np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\latel\Desktop\kool\Neuro\prax2\data\curve.csv',dtype =     'float', delimiter = ',')
curve_abs2 = np.empty_like(curve)
z = 1j
N = len(curve)
for i in range(0,N-1):
    curve_abs2[i] =0
    for k in range(0,N-1):
        curve_abs2[i] += (curve[i]*np.exp((-1)*z*(np.pi)*i*((k-1)/N)))

for i in range(0,N):
    curve_abs2[i] = abs(curve_abs2[i])/(2*len(curve_abs2))

#curve_abs = (np.abs(np.fft.fft(curve)))
#pp.plot(curve_abs)
pp.plot(curve_abs2)
pp.show()
```

The code behind # gives me 3 values. But this is just ... different

Wrong ^^ this code: http://www.upload.ee/image/3922681/Ex5problem.png

Correct using numpy.fft.fft(): http://www.upload.ee/image/3922682/Ex5numpyformulas.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. You are assigning complex values to the elements of `curve_abs2`, so it should be declared to be complex, e.g. `curve_abs2 = np.empty_like(curve, dtype=np.complex128)`.  (And I would recommend using the name, say, `curve_fft` instead of `curve_abs2`.)
2. In python, `range(low, high)` gives the sequence `[low, low + 1, ..., high - 2, high - 1]`, so instead of `range(0, N - 1)`, you must use `range(0, N)` (which can be simplified to `range(N)`, if you want).
3. You are missing a factor of 2 in your formula.  You could fix this by using `z = 2j`.
4. In the expression that is being summed in the inner loop, you are indexing `curve` as `curve[i]`, but this should be `curve[k]`.
5. Also in that expression, you don't need to subtract 1 from k, because the `k` loop ranges from 0 to N - 1.
6. Because `k` and `N` are integers and you are using Python 2.7, the division in the expression `(k-1)/N` will be integer division, and you'll get 0 for all `k`.  To fix this and the previous problem, you can change that term to `k / float(N)`.

If you fix those issues, when the first double loop finishes, the array `curve_abs2` (now a complex array) should match the result of `np.fft.fft(curve)`.  It won't be exactly the same, but the differences should be very small.

You could eliminate that double loop altogether using numpy vectorized calculations, but that is a topic for another question.