# python manual fft botched

Tags: python, numpy, fft

Im trying to repoduce the fft functions in python. Iv'e seen a similar question [Manual fft not giving me same results as fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172619/manual-fft-not-giving-me-same-results-as-fft) here, but I'm having trouble seeing if i'm doing the same error or a different one.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr

N=9 ### 10 -1 
MC=10

###Genrate soem data
data=complex(1,0)*npr.uniform(size=(N,MC))+complex(0,1)*npr.uniform(size=(N,MC))

naive_fft=complex(1,0)*np.zeros((N,MC))
for K in range(N):
    for m in range(N):
        phase=(2*np.pi*K*m)/float(N+1)
        naive_fft[K,:]=naive_fft[K,:]+data[m,:]*np.exp(complex(0,1)*phase)

fft=np.fft.fft(data,axis=0)
ifft=np.fft.ifft(data,axis=0)
print('fft')
print(naive_fft-fft)
print('ifft')
print(naive_fft-ifft*(N+1.0))
```

Comparing my results to the numpy fft i cannot reproduce neither fft nor ifft (only the `naive_fft[0,:]` seem to match the `fft[0,:]` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to mention. First of all, in Python we use `1j` to represent the imaginary unit, not `complex(0, 1)`. If you would like to compare your result to numpy, then you have to check how numpy implements the fft. See the [Numpy FFT docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft) for details. You'll find that numpy follows the most common fft definition, which uses a negative exponent. Furthermore, `float(N+1)` in your phase is simply wrong. It must read `N`.
All in all you have:

```
# ...
naive_fft = np.zeros((N,MC), dtype='complex')
for K in range(N):
    for m in range(N):
        phase=(-2*np.pi*K*m) / float(N)
        naive_fft[K] += data[m] * np.exp(phase*1j)

xfft = np.fft.fft(data, axis=0)
# ...
```

Test it with

```
>>> np.isclose(xfft, naive_fft).all()
    True
```

The inverse transformation works analogously but with a positive exponent.

Comment: thanks. you saved me. That range(N) gives 0,....,N-1 is still a bit strange no me.